# EC2 Nginx load testing

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

Can somebody provide statistics of how many transactions different ec2 servers can handle on nginx + php-fpm? Consider the PHP script to be as simple as this:

```
<?php exit; ?>
```

Comment: They have free trial accounts for you to test things like this. http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: I am pretty sure some would have worked that out. I am getting stuck at processing 8000 request per second on a 120gb 16 processor machine. I am using siege to generate load.

Comment: optimized worker process threads and php child to reach 13k transactions per second